# Bivariate distribution $P(X = Y)$

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

If I have a discrete bivariate distribution with a probability mass function defined as

$$p(x, y) = \frac{x+y}{21}$$

for $x = 1, 2, 3$ and $y = 1,2$,

is then $P(X = Y)$ found by taking the following sum;

$$P(X = Y) = \sum_{\lbrace x,y |x = y \rbrace}p(x,y)?$$

I found the answer to be $P(X = Y) = \frac{2}{7}.$ Thanks.

Comment: yup, $p(1,1)+p(2,2) = \frac{2}{21}+\frac{4}{21} = \frac{2}{7}$

Comment: Perfect, cheers.